# cpu cores stuck on 100 percent cpu utilization

Tags: java, tomcat, infinite-loop, cpu-usage

I am running a java web application in tomcat deployed on aws with 2 cores. The problem is after every 2-3 days both cpu cores get stuck on 100 percent cpu utilization and application becomes very slow. By taking the three thread dumps of tomcat within 10 sec interval when cpu was stuck 100 percent I found two threads which are causing the problem. Here is the stack trace .

```
Thread 1 :

http-bio-8080-exec-10 - priority:10 - threadId:0x00007fda4005a800 - nativeId:0x526e - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.nextRequest(AbstractInputBuffer.java:229)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
- locked <0x00000000f4102c60> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2nd thread : 

http-bio-8080-exec-3 - priority:10 - threadId:0x00007fda24096800 - nativeId:0x524e - state:RUNNABLE
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.nextRequest(AbstractInputBuffer.java:229)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
- locked <0x00000000f4102ca0> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms look like this Tomcat bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57544

The solution is to update your Tomcat to a more recent version.

> Comment #5 - Mark Thomas 2015-02-06 18:03:54 UTC
>
> This has been fixed in trunk (9.0.x development), 8.0.x for 8.0.19 onwards and 7.0.x for 7.0.60 onwards.